# Recursive function in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, web, phantomjs, settimeout

I'm having trouble seeing why my recursive function with a `setTimeout` is being invoked once when it should be more than that because of the base case.

```
page.open('', function() {
  var images = page.evaluate(function() {
    var count = 0;
    var data = [];
    function keepScrolling() {
      count += 1;
      if (count > 1000) {
        console.log('DONE');
      } else {
        console.log('count: ' + count);
        data.push(count);
        setTimeout(keepScrolling, 1000);
      }
    }
    keepScrolling();
    return data;
  });
  console.log(images);
});
```

When this is being invoked inside of `page.open` the call to `keepScrolling` only shows `count` being incremented one time instead of one thousand times like I'd expect. Is there something I need to do to get the recursive function to invoke more than once? I'd expect `data` to have a length of 1000 but it's of size 1. If I were to run this in the browser, it would run like I would expect.

The console output from running the above.

```
> phantomjs file.js
count: 1
[1]
```

Comment: The function you pass to `page.evaluate` returns after `keepScrolling` is called once, that is because `setTimeout` is async.

Comment: I extracted the recursive function out and ran it, and it runs fine. The base case never runs though for you, so it looks like it's being terminated.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that's correct. That piece of code will run like you'd expect when not running inside of `page.evaluate`. It does terminate with the base case because it's incremented every run and then checks to see if it's greater than 1000, then exits. The `return` statement would be better because it's clearer and more explicit.

Comment: I agree with @Titus' assessment.. not too familiar with phantomjs so dont know how one would force the async function to return.. probably something with `Promises`/`async/await`?

Comment: @Titus Do you have any ideas what would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you define the function that you pass to `page.evaluate` as `async` (`page.evaluate(async function() {....}`) ?

Comment: Please add `page.onError` callback to your code and check if there are any errors. You function could run one time because of the errors in the end of it.